# How to scrape player data from RealGM using Scrapy?

Tags: python, scrapy

To start, what I'm trying to do is scrape fields from RealGM, an example of this is:
https://basketball.realgm.com/player/player/Summary/1
https://basketball.realgm.com/player/player/Summary/160000

I'm trying to pull each piece of information from the players profile box, so I in the first example I want to pull:
Greg Oden C  #20
Born: Jan 22, 1988 (33 years old)
Birthplace/Hometown: Buffalo, New York
Nationality: United States
Height: 7-0 (213cm)     Weight: 273 (124kg)
Draft Entry: 2007 NBA Draft
Pre-Draft Team: Ohio State (Fr)
High School: Lawrence North High School [Indianapolis, Indiana]

I'm not having much success, the code I was able to get below works in pulling the href, which isn't perfect but I can work with it. The issue is I'm getting an error, and I think that's because not all of the players have the same data fields, the above example is the maximum output I would want, but there are some players who won't have a birthdate, some won't have a pre-draft team, etc. So for those I need it to just pull a blank for that field, and continue scraping. Pulling a field like the height/weight where there is no href and everything is wrapped in  I have had no success in pulling, whenever I reference that section it pulls a blank.

Any help would be appreciated! This is what I have so far but I'm stuck:

```
import scrapy

class RealGMSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "players"

    start_urls = [
            'https://basketball.realgm.com/player/player/Summary/1',
'https://basketball.realgm.com/player/player/Summary/2',
'https://basketball.realgm.com/player/player/Summary/160000'


    ]

    def parse(self, response):

        for player in response.css('.profile-box .container , .level-1'):
                yield {
                        'name': player.css('span::text')[1].get,
                        'link': player.css('a.selected').attrib['href'],
                        'bday': player.css('.half-column-left img+ p a').attrib['href'],
                        'htwn': player.css('p:nth-child(4) a').attrib['href'],
                        'ntion': player.css('.half-column-left p~ p+ p a').attrib['href'],
                        'cteam': player.css('.half-column-right img+ p a').attrib['href'],
                        'agent': player.css('.half-column-right p:nth-child(5) a').attrib['href'],
                        'draftyr': player.css('p:nth-child(6) a').attrib['href'],
                        'earlyen': player.css('p:nth-child(7) a').attrib['href'],
                        'drafted': player.css('p:nth-child(8) a').attrib['href'],
                        'predraft': player.css('p:nth-child(9) a').attrib['href'],
                        'hs': player.css('p:nth-child(10) a').attrib['href']

                }
```

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, I was able to use BeautifulSoup!

```
import csv ;import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv
import re

url_list = ['https://basketball.realgm.com/player/player/Summary/2',
            'https://basketball.realgm.com/player/player/Summary/1']

for url in url_list:
    r = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')

    player = soup.find_all('div', class_='wrapper clearfix container')[0]

    playerprofile = re.sub(
        r'\n\s*\n', r'\n', player.get_text().strip(), flags=re.M)

    output = playerprofile + "\n"
```